# Make my python password manager gui executable on my desktop

Tags: python, pyside6, linux-mint-21

i made a simple password manager in pyside6 and i am wondering how i can make it executable to actually use it. I've tried forums and chatGPT and nothing seems to work, i even somehow broke pyside6 at one point. i run linux mint 21 if that helps.

Comment: Check out `pyinstaller`

Comment: okay i will. last i checked pyinstaller only works with older versions of python.

Comment: 1. You can have multiple (major and minor) versions of python installed; 2. Since you're on linux, you don't need to make anything special to make a python file executable: just add a proper [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) to the top of the main script and make it executable by setting its properties (either through the UI, or using chmod).

Comment: Checkout the following for an approach which could be helpful [python-self-contained-runnable-package-template](https://sr.ht/~tpapastylianou/python-self-contained-runnable-package-template/)